# Vue Style Shared Component

Tags: css, sass, vuejs2, vue-component

I am working on a Vue component that is going to be shared between two different platforms (Web/Mobile). I also want the component to have the same style/look on both platforms. Each platform is using a different CSS framework.

What is the best way to go about making the style/look the same? Without having two completely different components.

I can think of a few options

1. Having a prop to set the style
2. Two different templates and use a mixin
3. Similar to 1 but have a CSS module that can be toggled
4. Scope the style so it is not dependent on the platform css framework

Comment: Generally most frameworks have slightly different looks from one another, so even if you can customize them until they look the same, it seems like it would just be better to use one mobile-first framework throughout the entire project.

Comment: If this is a one-time problem (if you're only doing this for one component), then #1 or #3  seem to be the easiest; however, #4 might be less of a hassle if you need to do this for multiple components.